# Как перевести NSButton в нажатое состояние?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, ios, macos

Есть три кнопки для сортировки списка.

[image]

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку она оставалась нажатой, показывая тем самым текущий режим сортировки.

Как установить NSButton в нажатое состояние?

Comment: Никак, просто меняйте бекграунд кнопки.

Answer (score 1):

Можно перевести кнопку в состояние "On".

```
self.button.state = NSOnState;
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте стиль Recessed тип Push On Push Off
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]